# How to display logged in user information in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I have a multi user application in PHP, I am using, for example, chrome, but I am also logged with another one or more browsers.

Is there a way to see the information for all the logged browser? Like for example, in chrome display

**"you are logged with your current browser (chrome) and with another (firefox)"**

and when I go in firefox display

**"you are logged with your current browser (firefox) and with another (chrome)"**

Comment: If you store sessions in a way that you can query every session currently active *for a particular user*, and you store the browser names in those sessions, that should be pretty simple. PHP's default file-based session store doesn't really allow for this. You'd need to replace that with your own database-based session store or similar queryable alternative.

Comment: I don't know why there is so much down vote on this question and even with the answers. please can someone clarify.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In PHP, you will use the user agent server variable to get it i.e

```
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

// You can also extend the code to get the specific user agent

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
    $ub = "Firefox";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Google Chrome';
    $ub = "Chrome";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Apple Safari';
    $ub = "Safari";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Opera';
    $ub = "Opera";
}
elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
{
    $bname = 'Netscape';
    $ub = "Netscape";
}
```

You will store the $bname, user iD, date of last login in a current login table.
Make sure user's login activities is being captured in SESSION and recorder in the database. 
Each time there is a new login, you will go to the current login table to check if the user is active, add the new login detail, then use all those information to display what you want to display to the user.